# Calculate Tic-Tac-Toe Game Winner C# || Online Practice assessment test question ||

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I'm trying to figure out if I coded this correctly according to directions within the image.
Please inform me on what I did wrong.

// Here's my Code think it right but not 100% sure

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TicTacToe.Template
{
public enum CellState
{
[Description("EMPTY")]
Empty,
[Description("X")]
X,
[Description("O")]
O
}

public enum Winner
{
[Description("IN_PROGRESS")]
InProgress,
[Description("TIED")]
Tied,
[Description("X")]
X,
[Description("O")]
O
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
Type type = value.GetType();
string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
if (name != null)
{
FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
if (field != null)
{
DescriptionAttribute attr =
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
if (attr != null)
{
return attr.Description;
}
}
}
return null;
}
}

public class TicTacToe
{

/**
* Evaluates the game board to determine the winner.
* <p>
* If the game is still in progress, then this method returns InProgress.
* If the game is tied, then this method returns Tied.
* Otherwise, returns the winner - either X or O.
*
* @param cells - an array of 9 game cells that forms the 3x3 grid of the board.
* @return the Winner - InProgress, Tied, X, or O
*/
```

//Main part of the code where I added in functionality this function below was blank before.

```
public static Winner CalculateWinner(CellState[] cells)
        { 
            if (cells[0] == cells[1] && cells[1] == cells[2])
            {
                 return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[3] == cells[4] && cells[4] == cells[5])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[6] == cells[7] && cells[7] == cells[8])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }    
            else if (cells[0] == cells[3] && cells[3] == cells[6])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[1] == cells[4] && cells[4] == cells[7])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[2] == cells[5] && cells[5] == cells[8])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[0] == cells[4] && cells[4] == cells[8])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else if (cells[2] == cells[4] && cells[4] == cells[6])
            {
                return Winner.X;
            }
            else
            {
                return Winner.Tied;
            }
        }

public static CellState[] ConvertInputLineToCellStateArray(string inputLine)
{
if (inputLine.Length != 9)
{
throw new ArgumentException("Invalid state string. Should have 9 characters.");
}

List<CellState> cellStates = new List<CellState>();

foreach (char c in inputLine)
{
if (c == '_') cellStates.Add(CellState.Empty);
if (c == 'X') cellStates.Add(CellState.X);
if (c == 'O') cellStates.Add(CellState.O);
}

return cellStates.ToArray();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
string inputLine;

while ((inputLine = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
Console.WriteLine(CalculateWinner(ConvertInputLineToCellStateArray(inputLine)).GetDescription());
}
}
}
}
```

PLease ignore these paragraphs below it just basic Rules, info and history about Tic-Tac Toe. It wasn't letting me post cause it was saying I had too much code. Explanation  in the image Above. Thank You.
Tic-Tac-Toe is a simple and fun game for 2 players, X and O. It is played on a 3x3 grid. Each player's goal is to make 3 in a row.

Typically, X starts first, but in Gametable's Tabletop Tic Tac Toe, Player 1 starts first on the first game and Player 2 (or the computer) starts first on the next game. The starting player continues to alternate from game to game. This helps keep gameplay fair over time.

Players take turns placing their Mark, X or O, on an open square in the grid. The first player to make 3 of their own mark in a row vertically, horizontally, or diagonally wins the game.

If all 9 squares are filled and neither player has 3 in a row, the game is considered a Tie.

The expert artificial intelligence (AI) will play a perfect game. Try your best to Tie it for as long as you can!

ZERO-SUM GAME
Tic-Tac-Toe is a zero-sum game, which means that if both players are playing their best, the game will end in a Tie. However, if you learn how to play tic-tac-toe and master some simple strategies, then you'll be able to not only play, but to win the majority of the time.

HISTORY
Tic-Tac-Toe is a long beloved classic pen and paper or board game for two players. Variations of Tic Tac Toe have been played since the Roman Empire and 3 in a row games can be traced all the way back to ancient Egypt!

NOUGHTS AND CROSSES
Tic Tac Toe is known by a few other names around the world. The most common of these is "Noughts and Crosses" and it is sometimes simply referred to as the "XO game."

gametable.org
Gametable is an upcoming interactive entertainment company for the desktop and mobile world. We currently have three free online games- dots and boxes, checkers, and tic tac toe. We're actively developing more fun titles by the day. We're offering ad-free online games for a limited time so pull up a chair to the game table today! We value your privacy as much as you do! Privacy Policy, Cookie Policy, and Terms & Conditions.

Comment: you're testing if cells 0,1 and 2 are the same, and then say X wins... but if all three are O, they are the same - but shouldn't O be the winner? ;) by the way: tic tac toe is [solved](https://xkcd.com/832/), and the best result you can get against a perfect player is a tie.

Comment: Your CalculateWinner function only returns two possible options: Winner.X or Winner.Tied. As Franz pointed out O in cells 0, 1 & 2 will report X as winner, but so will empty in each of those.  There is no provision for Winner.Y or Winner.InProgress to be returned. Definately do some more testing to uncover where you logic is wrong. Consider setting up unit tests to automatically test the outcome.

Comment: OK thanks for explaining this to me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very straight forward implementation

```
public static Winner CalculateWinner(CellState[] cells)
{
    var linesToCheck = new []
    {
        // horizontal
        new [] { cells[0], cells[1], cells[2] },
        new [] { cells[3], cells[4], cells[5] },
        new [] { cells[6], cells[7], cells[8] },
        // vertical
        new [] { cells[0], cells[3], cells[6] },
        new [] { cells[1], cells[4], cells[7] },
        new [] { cells[2], cells[5], cells[8] },
        // diagonal
        new [] { cells[0], cells[4], cells[8] },
        new [] { cells[6], cells[4], cells[2] },
    };

    foreach (var line in linesToCheck)
    {
        if (line.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            switch (line.First())
            {
                case CellState.X: 
                    return Winner.X;
                case CellState.O:
                    return Winner.O;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (cells.Any( c => c == CellState.Empty ))
        return Winner.InProgress;
    else
        return Winner.Tied;
}
```

Comment: So did my method CalculateWinner not have all the possibility for someone winning at tic-tac-toe?